# AngularJS and Select2 model state not rendering after select box

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I'm running into some kind of issue where if I have a scope variable defined, it shows before the HTML reaches the select2 box, but if I show the variable after the select2 element, it doesn't render.

Here's my HTML:

```
{{stateIsValid}}
<select id="state" name="state" class="select2" ng-change="stateChanged()" ng-model="client.state">
    <option value="state">State...</option>
    <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
</select>
{{stateIsValid}}
```

The JS just establishes the select2 box, and sets a scope variable:

```
$('.select2#state').select2();
angular.extend($scope, {
    stateIsValid: false
});
```

My issue is, in the HTML selection, the first {{stateIsValid}} renders "false", but the second doesn't render at all and just displays {{stateIsValid}}.

I don't get any console errors. 
This seems to be specifically an error with the select2 rendering itself. If I comment out the select2() initialization, then everything works fine.

I'm trying to get this working so I can show a custom error below the select box.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: You could try using angular wrapper for select2 https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Comment: Tried it but it isn't rendering, will give it some more time later. Thanks!

Comment: Could you submit a plunkr or jsfiddle example?

Comment: You should use ui-select2. You really don't need to be doing DOM selectors for this sort of issue. If you're determined not to use ui-select2, can you recreate your issue in a plnkr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There something weird on `select2` initialization method.
You can solve with a `$timeout` wrap.

```
  $timeout(function() {
     $('.select2#state').select2();  
  })
```

here the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/i1HNAtfHfNkq2srAff5S?p=preview